# How to calculate the maximum 60 minute total in an irregular rainfall timeseries in R?

Tags: r, lag, cumulative-sum

I have an ongoing irregular timeseries of rainfall data recorded using a 0.5mm tipping bucket.

E.g.

| Date and time | Rainfall |
| --- | --- |
| 11/05/2021 11:05:17 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 11:15:10 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 11:20:04 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 11:28:22 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 11:33:25 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 11:36:39 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 11:39:50 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 11:41:43 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 11:43:35 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 11:44:57 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 11:47:02 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 11:48:42 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 11:53:04 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 11:58:33 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 12:01:27 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 12:02:52 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 12:07:35 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 12:10:32 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 12:12:55 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 12:16:22 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 12:17:45 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 12:20:14 | 0.5 |
| 11/05/2021 12:22:26 | 0.5 |

During events i'd like to be able to calculate:

- rolling 60minute totals
- maximum 60minute total for the event (not hourly total from 11am to 12, 12 to 1pm, etc)

i.e. in the example above: a 60 minute period could start at 12:07:35 and include back to 11:15:10 (the 60 minute period starts on the exact hh:mm:ss of the tip).

Knowing the max total helps us compare between events, and against forecasts.

**My thought process so far:**

I've been calculating the rate of rise for water level (which records at a 5 minute interval) using the lag function.

```
River_Hour_RoR <- mutate(River, RoR = Stage - lag(Stage, n = 12))
```

I thought perhaps I could use the sum/cumulative-sum function combined with the lag function (in a similar way to the WL rate of rise) but am unsure how to specify the 60 minute time interval.

Any thoughts on how to do this, or a different approach would be much appreciated! Thanks :)!

Answer (score 2):

```
library(lubridate)
library(slider)


# convert to POSIXct datetime format
df1$Date.and.time = lubridate::mdy_hms(df1$Date.and.time)

# sum over prior 60 minutes using slider::slide_index
df1$hourly_total = slider::slide_index_dbl(df1$Rainfall, df1$Date.and.time, sum, .before = minutes(60))

df1[df1$hourly_total == max(df1$hourly_total),]
#         Date.and.time Rainfall hourly_total
#23 2021-11-05 12:22:26      0.5           10
```

Alternately, here's a `dplyr` approach where we take a cumulative sum of the data, plus a lagged-one-hour version with negative rainfall. This will allow a cumulative tally of just the totals over the last 60m.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(
  df1,
  df1 %>% mutate(Date.and.time = Date.and.time + dhours(1),
                 Rainfall = -Rainfall)) %>%
  arrange(Date.and.time) %>%
  mutate(Rainfall_60m = cumsum(Rainfall))
```

If we feed that into ggplot, we can see how that works visually:

```
... %>%
ggplot(aes(Date.and.time, Rainfall_60m)) + 
geom_step() +
geom_col(aes(y = Rainfall))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using *data.table*, with a self-join to only those records in the last 60 minutes:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

dat[, Datetime := as.POSIXct(Datetime , format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC") ]
dat[, subthour := Datetime - as.difftime(1, units="hours") ]

dat[, Sum_Rainfall := 
  dat[
    dat,
    on = c("Datetime>=subthour", "Datetime<=Datetime"),
    sum(Rainfall),
    by=.EACHI
  ]$V1
]
dat[, subthour := NULL]
```

Result:

```
#               Datetime Rainfall Sum_Rainfall
# 1: 2021-05-11 11:05:17      0.5          0.5
# 2: 2021-05-11 11:15:10      0.5          1.0
# 3: 2021-05-11 11:20:04      0.5          1.5
# 4: 2021-05-11 11:28:22      0.5          2.0
# 5: 2021-05-11 11:33:25      0.5          2.5
# 6: 2021-05-11 11:36:39      0.5          3.0
# 7: 2021-05-11 11:39:50      0.5          3.5
# 8: 2021-05-11 11:41:43      0.5          4.0
# 9: 2021-05-11 11:43:35      0.5          4.5
#10: 2021-05-11 11:44:57      0.5          5.0
#11: 2021-05-11 11:47:02      0.5          5.5
#12: 2021-05-11 11:48:42      0.5          6.0
#13: 2021-05-11 11:53:04      0.5          6.5
#14: 2021-05-11 11:58:33      0.5          7.0
#15: 2021-05-11 12:01:27      0.5          7.5
#16: 2021-05-11 12:02:52      0.5          8.0
#17: 2021-05-11 12:07:35      0.5          8.0
#18: 2021-05-11 12:10:32      0.5          8.5
#19: 2021-05-11 12:12:55      0.5          9.0
#20: 2021-05-11 12:16:22      0.5          9.0
#21: 2021-05-11 12:17:45      0.5          9.5
#22: 2021-05-11 12:20:14      0.5          9.5
#23: 2021-05-11 12:22:26      0.5         10.0
#               Datetime Rainfall Sum_Rainfall
```

Where `dat` was:

```
dat <- structure(list(Datetime = c("11/05/2021 11:05:17", "11/05/2021 11:15:10", 
"11/05/2021 11:20:04", "11/05/2021 11:28:22", "11/05/2021 11:33:25", 
"11/05/2021 11:36:39", "11/05/2021 11:39:50", "11/05/2021 11:41:43", 
"11/05/2021 11:43:35", "11/05/2021 11:44:57", "11/05/2021 11:47:02", 
"11/05/2021 11:48:42", "11/05/2021 11:53:04", "11/05/2021 11:58:33", 
"11/05/2021 12:01:27", "11/05/2021 12:02:52", "11/05/2021 12:07:35", 
"11/05/2021 12:10:32", "11/05/2021 12:12:55", "11/05/2021 12:16:22", 
"11/05/2021 12:17:45", "11/05/2021 12:20:14", "11/05/2021 12:22:26"
), Rainfall = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the first column to POSIXct and then use `findInterval` to find the row number of the time 60 minutes (3600 seconds) back.  `w[i]` is defined as the number of rows to total for the ith row of the data frame.  Using that run rollapplyr which allows the width to be the vector w.  w may be of interest since it shows how many rows were involved in each total.  We can then use which.max to get the row with the maximum total.

```
library(zoo)

tt <- as.POSIXct(DF[[1]], format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
w <- seq_along(tt) - findInterval(tt - 3600, tt)
DF2 <- transform(DF, total = rollapplyr(Rainfall, w, sum, fill = NA), w = w,
              check.names = FALSE)

head(DF2)
##         Date and time Rainfall total w
## 1 11/05/2021 11:05:17      0.5   0.5 1
## 2 11/05/2021 11:15:10      0.5   1.0 2
## 3 11/05/2021 11:20:04      0.5   1.5 3
#3 4 11/05/2021 11:28:22      0.5   2.0 4
## 5 11/05/2021 11:33:25      0.5   2.5 5
## 6 11/05/2021 11:36:39      0.5   3.0 6

DF2[which.max(DF2$total), ]
##          Date and time Rainfall total  w
## 23 11/05/2021 12:22:26      0.5    10 20
```